# Docker .Net Core app on Ubuntu not opening in localhost:8000

Tags: .net, bash, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a docker app with .Net Core on Windows and am trying to get it to run on Ubuntu.  I have docker and .Net Core running without error.

When I run "sudo docker-compose up" it runs the server and is listening on "http://+:80." But I can't open that in the browser.  On Windows every one I am working with can get it to load up on localhost:8000.

When I run docker-compose this is what I get:

```
sudo docker-compose up
Starting webui
Starting projects_api
Starting profile_api
Starting identity_api
Attaching to projects_api, profile_api, webui, identity_api
profile_api     | Hosting environment: Development
profile_api     | Content root path: /app
projects_api    | Hosting environment: Development
profile_api     | Now listening on: http://+:80
projects_api    | Content root path: /app
profile_api     | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
projects_api    | Now listening on: http://+:80
projects_api    | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
identity_api    | info: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[0]
identity_api    |       User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
identity_api    | Hosting environment: Development
identity_api    | Content root path: /app
identity_api    | Now listening on: http://+:80
identity_api    | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Now those are the methods I have tried, but, on windows they use Powershell scripts to ping the server.  But I don't know how to convert the powershell to bash. I thought maybe if I converted it to bash I could run the app. This is the powershell script that supposedly runs the server:

```
    param(
    [string]$host_url = "http://localhost"
)


@(
    "$host_url`:5001/api/health/ping",
    "$host_url`:5002/api/health/ping",
    "$host_url`:5003/api/health/ping",
    "$host_url`:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration"
) |
ForEach-Object { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ } |
Select-Object StatusCode, StatusDescription, Content
```

Comment: Can you add the compose file please?

Comment: @johnharris85 Thanks for the comment.  I added the whole repo so you can look at it. I would love to get it so I can just open it in the browser with the localhost!

Comment: Try `localhost:5000`.

Comment: @johnharris85 sweet, that worked!  thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `docker-compose up` is run it looks for two files by default, `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml`. The `docker-compose.yml` in your repo doesn't specify any mappings but the `docker-compose.override.yml` [has a mapping of](https://github.com/joelt11753/CVPZ/blob/master/docker-compose.override.yml#L7) `5000` on the host to `80` in the UI container. Not sure how your colleagues are hitting the UI on `8080` though unless they've mapped something differently.